# How does docker go-wrapper script works

Tags: docker, go

hey can anyone explain to me what docker `go-wrapper` should do ?
https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/master/go-wrapper
following this comment:

> This script allows us to take a generic directory of Go source files
>   such as "/go/src/app" and determine that the canonical "import path"
>   of where that code expects to live and reference itself is
>   "github.com/jsmith/my-cool-app".  It will then ensure that
>   "/go/src/github.com/jsmith/my-cool-app" is a symlink to "/go/src/app",
>   which allows us to build and run it under the proper package name.

I understand that if I am developing a project under mine github go path then mounting it `/go/src/app` inside a docker container will work with imports still remained unchanged (github imports) correct ?

```
COPY . /go/src/app
WORKDIR /go/src/app

RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install
```

however when i try to install/run with vendors using dep

```
go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
dep init
dep ensure -update
```

it downloads my repo to vendor and then tries to import it from there why is that ?

Comment: Take a look at the FAQs for dep. There are is a sample on how to use Docker with dep: https://github.com/golang/dep/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-use-dep-with-docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with dep so I cannot comment on *that* part of your problem. However, the text you quoted relates to the canonical import path and you did not say you are using a canonical import path. You MUST use a canonical import path to get `go-wrapper` to behave like described in the quote.

Once your package has a canonical import path (like `package main // import "github.com/user/projname"`) then `go-wrapper` will recognize that special comment and create a symlink from `go/src/github.com/user/projname` to `/go/src/app` *inside* the docker container. This symlink will prevent `go-wrapper download` from downloading sub-packages like `github.com/user/projname/subpackage` from the remote (github.com).

This behavior is especially useful for me when I am developing locally because I want to test my local changes to sub-packages before I commit them to the remote. If `go-wrapper` did not symlink for me, then it would go to the remote and download each of the sub-packages, which means I would be getting the older version instead of my locally edited sub-packages.